# Error: No viable overloaded operator[] for type vector<int>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Hi I am trying to practice c++ and came across a error while solving a problem, I am using vectors in my code and getting error where I added two elements in vector through reference operator'[]'

**C++**

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int> temp;
        int p = 0;
        for (auto i = nums.begin(); i != (nums.end() - 1); ++i) {
            cout<<*i;
            p = nums[i]+nums[i+1];                 //Error is in this line
            if ((p) == target) {
                temp.push_back(i);
                temp.push_back(i + 1);
                return temp;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Error: No viable overloaded operator[] for type vector**

Comment: `i` is an iterator, not an index, you might want `p = *i + *(i + 1);`.

Comment: BTW, your function doesn't return if not found.

Comment: [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) (with custom predicate) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code, you cannot mix iterators with numeric values.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int> temp;
        int p = 0;
        for (auto i = nums.begin(); i != (nums.end() - 1); ++i) {
            cout << *i;
            p = *i + *(i + 1);                 //now code works fine 
            if ((p) == target) {
                temp.push_back(*i);
                temp.push_back(*(i + 1));
                return temp;

            }
        }


    }
};
```

when you use loop using iterators you shouldn't access into a vector via [] operator, because iterators are pointers to elements of the vector. simply use *i to access value iterator points to.

Comment: As often, comment go out of sync, `//Error is in this line` is no longer accurate.

Comment: Is there any way of getting the index number of the iterator pointing to.

Comment: i think that it requires you to change your for loop a little bit, because I doubt iterators support support it. You can just make basic for (int i = 0; i< nums.size()-2; i++) loop and then you can use it as you did before

Answer (score 0):

`i` is an iterator, not an index, so you don't need `[]` at all.

```
class Solution {
public:
    std::vector<int> twoSum(std::vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        for (auto i = nums.begin(); i != (nums.end() - 1); ++i) {
            std::cout<<*i;
            if ((*i + *(i + 1)) == target) {
                return { *i, *(i + 1) };
            }
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("no solution found");
    }
};
```

However rather than writing the loop yourself, you could use the existing `std::adjacent_find`

```
class Solution {
public:
    std::vector<int> twoSum(std::vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        auto i = std::adjacent_find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), [target](int a, int b) { 
            std::cout << a;
            return (a + b) == target; 
        });
        if (i != nums.end()) {
            return { *i, *(i + 1) };
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("no solution found");
    }
};
```